# How to plot a stacked bar chart with multiple variables with seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a dataset as shown below:

```
Season  Phylum          Assigned    Yield
1   Acidobacteria       157363      High
1   Ignavibacteriae     15158       Low
1   Gemmatimonadetes    16408       High
2   Actinobacteria      143507      High
2   Chloroflexi         252391      Low
3   Cyanobacteria       172041      High
3   Firmicutes          74769       High
3   Acidobacteria       222991      Low
3   Bacteroidetes       280246      Low
```

I used this code, however, failed to achieve the plot i wanted

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter, MultipleLocator
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("./bacterial_phylum_abundance_root_allseasons.csv",sep='\t')
print(df)

sns.set_style('whitegrid')
g = sns.displot(data=df, x='Yield', hue='Phylum', col='Season', multiple='fill', shrink=0.7, palette='turbo')
g.set(xlabel='', ylabel='')
g.axes[0, 0].yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(.1))
g.axes[0, 0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
g.axes[0, 0].set_xlim(-.6, 1.6)
sns.despine(left=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
plt.show()
```

[Output obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuoIv.jpg)

I would like to make a stacked bar chart that looks something like this which included all season (1,2,3):
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sb2qY.png)

Did really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you maybe show us what plot your code achieved? I have attempted to replicate your dataframe and used your code and seems to be working as intended.

Comment: Hi @KimHyunBin, I'll post my output below. thank you

Comment: @KimHyunBin Anwering your previous question, yes,i would like the 'assigned' value for each phylum to show at the y-axis. And the original image doesn't show the 'assigned' values too. Just used it as an example, bcs thats how i want it, y-axis to reflect the 'assigned' values, hue/color to reflect the phylum name and x-axis which groups the 'yield' &'season'. Sorry if i confused you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are seeing just 50% for each bar is because the height is being dictated by the number of rows in each case. So, it is either 100% (single) or 50% (two entries). One way to get around it is to use `stat='probability` in the displot. However, your `Assigned` value is in a column and probability looks for the number of rows. So, I have used `repeat()` to create the number of rows of same info based on the number in `Assigned`. Not sure if this is the most efficient way, but should give you the result you need. Data is what you provided. See if this works...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter, MultipleLocator
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
sns.set_style('whitegrid')

df1=df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.Assigned)]  ##Used repeate to create rows as value in repeat

g = sns.displot(data=df1, x='Yield', hue='Phylum', col='Season', multiple='fill', shrink=0.7, stat='probability', palette='turbo') ##stat is probability
g.set(xlabel='', ylabel='')
g.axes[0, 0].yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(.1))
g.axes[0, 0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
g.axes[0, 0].set_xlim(-.6, 1.6)
sns.despine(left=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
plt.show()
```

**Plot**

[image]

**Improvement/change**

As you mentioned that the time taken is long, I made some adjustment to the code. Instead of `repeat()` which will add as many rows as the value of `Assigned` column, the percentages of each are calculated before `repeat()` is applied. So, there should just be a few hundred rows. The same result is received, although the precision might be at a 1% level. But think that is ok. See if this works.

```
df=pd.read_excel('myinput.xlsx', 'Sheet91')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter, MultipleLocator
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
print(df)
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
#df1=df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.Assigned)]

trans = df.groupby(['Season', 'Yield'])['Assigned'].transform('sum')
df['perc'] = round(df['Assigned']/trans * 100)
df1=df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.perc)]

#g = sns.displot(data=df, x='Yield', hue='Phylum', col='Season', multiple='fill', shrink=0.7, palette='turbo')
g = sns.displot(data=df1, x='Yield', hue='Phylum', col='Season', multiple='fill', shrink=0.7, stat='probability', palette='turbo')
g.set(xlabel='', ylabel='')
g.axes[0, 0].yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(.1))
g.axes[0, 0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
g.axes[0, 0].set_xlim(-.6, 1.6)
sns.despine(left=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried running this with the dataset i posted here as well as the extended version of dataset i have, but its been running for about an hour now without showing any output. Did it take this long to show the output on your end too?

Comment: Hi @sumitra - It took a couple of seconds. I was afraid that it might get slow when the assigned numbers are huge, as it might be in your real data. So, I have now made some adjustment to speed it up. See if this works. Check the improvement/change section for details

Comment: I tried out the adjusted script and ended up with an error 'ValueError: cannot set using a list-like indexer with a different length than the value"

Comment: Runs correctly for me without any errors. Which line is the error?

Comment: Oh that's strange. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "phylum_allseason.py", line 24, in <module>
    g = sns.displot(data=df1, x='Yield', hue='Phylum', col='Season', multiple='fill', shrink=0.7, stat='probability', palette='turbo')

Comment: Very difficult to find out as I am not getting the error. 1-Could be version of `seaborn` - mine is `0.11.1`. 2- More likely something to do with data. Run this code with the dataset you provided above(9 rows). If it runs, then check `df`, `trans` and `df1` to see if all data is available (no blanks/NULLs, `Assigned` in all ints, df and trans are of same length)

Comment: I finally got it!! Just had to upgrade my seaborn from 0.11.1 to 0.12.0. Works like a charm now. Thank you so much